# Using Respond.js with Shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify

I'm having issues getting Respond.js to work with Shopify due to CSS files being hosted on their CDN.

With Shopify, all assets (CSS, JS, and images) are hosted via a CDN. I'm unable to figure out the proper places to put the proxy files that are included with the Respond package.

Has anyone made this work? How'd you do it?

Comment: I too would love an answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue - the key being that the cross-domain proxy bundled with Respond.js doesn't work with Shopify as the proxy javascript has to be hosted on the same domain the page is served from.

I've developed a workaround for this that's only mildly hacky - it basically serves the cross-domain javascript as a page from your Shopify site.

The full solution is probably a bit long for a Stack Overflow answer, but you can read it in full here: [Using Respond.js with Shopify](http://gavinballard.com/using-respond.js-with-shopify/).

Hope this helps!